# Power BI Subtotals and Totals Wrong

Tags: powerbi

I did not use DAX to create subtotals or totals.
I simply put a Matrix Visual on the design pane, confirmed the underlying data is correct, and row and column totals are wrong.

See image below:

[image: Incorrect row and column totals]

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out

The monthly totals represent the values for each month of that year.
The row totals represent the values for the whole year.

Bingo